# Kingfisher LocalFileImageDataProvider DownsamplingImageProcessor resize data in memory

Tags: swift, kingfisher

Since `Kingfisher` introduced `LocalFileImageDataProvider` from `5.0`. I decided to switch to `Kingfisher` to load images from my disk instead of loading them directly. As they said,

```
// Compared to loading it directly, 
// you can get benefit of using Kingfisher's extension methods, 
// as well as applying `ImageProcessor`s and storing the image to `ImageCache` of Kingfisher.
```

It works great. since my images from disk are quite large (more than 1MB each).

---

So **The question is If I resize image size by using `DownsamplingImageProcessor` in `UICollectionView's Cell`, am I still able to access the original size images in the "Image's detail" page to show the full resolution image by still using like this**,

```
//The way loading image from "Image detail page"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let provider = LocalFileImageDataProvider(fileURL: url)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: provider)
```

So in "UICollectionView page" I can use it like this,

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let provider = LocalFileImageDataProvider(fileURL: url)
let processor = DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: size)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: provider, options: [.processor(processor)])
```

**So are they cached different images cache in the Kingfisher cache mechanism? Because they seem using the same `cacheKey` in `LocalFileImageDataProvider`.**

```swift
public init(fileURL: URL, cacheKey: String? = nil) {
  self.fileURL = fileURL
  self.cacheKey = cacheKey ?? fileURL.absoluteString
}
```

---

**Do I need to customise the the `cacheKey` for those two different pages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a different cache key. The `processor` has an identifier and it will be used to calculate the final cache key when storing in the cache. So everything should be fine to you (as your code snippet).

You can just print out the image size in the image setting method completion handler to confirm the image you are loading.

```swift
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        // The image was set to image view:
        print(value.image.size)
    //...
```